# Play Framework - Overriding a configuration array of object literals in tests

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0, automated-tests

I updated my application.conf file to accept an array of structured JSON literals for a particular configuration value:

```
auth.clientKeys = [
  {"id": "client1", "secret": "secretvalue1"},
  {"id": "client2", "secret": "secretvalue2"}
]
```

This seems to work just fine when accessing it in my application, but I'm unsure how I'm supposed to set these values in my tests using FakeApplication. I thought I could just use a map

```
FakeApplication(additionalConfiguration = Map(
"auth.clientKeys" -> Array(Map("id" -> "testClient", "secret" -> "testSecret"))))
```

but I get the error message

```
BugOrBroken: : bug in method caller: not valid to create ConfigValue from: [Lscala.collection.immutable.Map;@4997a288  (ConfigImpl.java:275)
```

How can I override these values in my tests?

UPDATE 1:

I've also tried using java collections in conjunction with ConfigValueFactory with no luck:

```
import collection.JavaConversions._
  def fakeApplicationConfig = FakeApplication(additionalConfiguration = Map(
    "auth.clientKeys" -> ConfigValueFactory.fromIterable(asJavaIterable(Array(ConfigValueFactory.fromMap(Map("id" -> "testClient", "secret" -> "testSecret")))))))
```

This results in a similar error:

```
 BugOrBroken: : bug in method caller: not valid to create ConfigValue from: ConfigString("testSecret")
```

UPDATE 2:

I still haven't found an approach that works, so I'm instead using a single JSON literal in my config to work around this issue:

```
auth.clientKeys = {"client1": "secretvalue1", "client2": "secretvalue2"}
```

This is less flexible, but it works for now, and I can test it by using fakeApplication:

```
FakeApplication(additionalConfiguration = Map(
"auth.clientKeys" -> Map("testClient" -> "testSecret", "testClient2" -> "testSecret2")))
```

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this? I have just encountered the same problem. Ended up not putting any additionalConfiguration and just putting everything in `Test.auth......` and my actual values in `Dev.auth....` and `Prod.auth....`. Not ideal though; I'd rather not do it like this.

Answer (score 0):

This is just a guess, but I think it may be because you're using an `immutable Map` meaning you can't update the values

Try using a `mutable.Map`

I've never tried doing something like that in a `conf` file, so can't be sure if that's the only issue though

Comment: Still no luck when I attempt to use:

    def fakeApplicationConfig = FakeApplication(additionalConfiguration = Map(
    "auth.clientKeys" -> scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer(scala.collection.mutable.Map("id" -> "testClient", "secret" -> "testSecret"))))

(Note that I can't replace the first map with a mutable structure - it doesn't compile)